# SQL search not returning any results when using ajax script

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to do a SQL search with an ajax script but it is not returning any results. I've looked it over 20 times but cannot spot the mistake. This is the part where there must be a problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AJAX Search Example</title>
    <script>
    function fetch() {
      // (A) GET SEARCH TERM
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append('ajax', 1);

      // (B) AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', "2-search.php");
      xhr.onload = function () {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.response),
            wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
        if (results.length > 0) {
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";
          for (let res of results) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
             line.innerHTML = `${res['category']} - ${res['oemnumber']} - ${res['price']}`;
            wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }
        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found"; }
      };
      xhr.send(data);
      return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form onsubmit="return fetch();">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS - USE HTTP:// NOT FILE://</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I use the form to show results on another page it works fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form method="post" action="1-form.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    // (B) PROCESS SEARCH WHEN FORM SUBMITTED
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      // (B1) SEARCH FOR USERS
      require "2-search.php";
      
      // (B2) DISPLAY RESULTS
      if (count($results) > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $r) {
          printf("<div>%s - %s</div> - %s</div>", $r['category'], $r['oemnumber'], $r['price']););
        }
      } else { echo "No results found"; }
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone spot the mistake causing it to not show any results? Thank you in advance :)

Edit: This is what I am getting in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbkmb.png)

Comment: Check your browser console tab see if there are any errors .

Comment: I added the utf-8 now it says: TypeError: Not enough arguments to Window.fetch.

Comment: One question I have been pondering. The file was working yesterday, I made some changes and it stopped working. I changed things back but it still did not work. I went to lunch and came back and it was working again. Could the problem be some sort of caching? And if so how would I stop that?